# Как добавить текст из select в кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется кнопка добавление товара в корзину.

```
 <a data-id="" data-size="">В корзину</a>
```

И select

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Не выбрано</option>
  <option value="1">38-XXS</option>
  <option value="2">40-XS</option>
  <option value="3">42-S</option>
</select>
<label>Выберите размер</label>
```

Как при выборе размера в select, чтобы он добавлялся в `data-size="38-XXS"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает! в атрибут добавляется! Обратите внимание заменил значения value у option.

```js
$('.size').on('change', function(){
 $('#a').attr('data-size', $(this).val());
  alert($('#a').attr('data-size'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='a' data-id="" data-size="">В корзину</a>
 <select class='size'>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Не выбрано</option>
  <option value="38-XXS">38-XXS</option>
  <option value="40-XS">40-XS</option>
  <option value="42-S">42-S</option>
</select>
<label>Выберите размер</label>
```

Comment: Вот это спасибо! Почему другие варианты не работали не пойму

Answer (score 0):

```js
let select = document.querySelector('#targetSelect');
let dataSize = document.querySelector('#targetLink');
let strUser;

select.addEventListener('click', e => {
  strUser = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(strUser);
  dataSize.setAttribute("data-size", strUser);
});
```

```html
<select id='targetSelect'>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Не выбрано</option>
  <option value="1">38-XXS</option>
  <option value="2">40-XS</option>
  <option value="3">42-S</option>
</select>
<label>Выберите размер</label>

<a id='targetLink' data-id="" data-size="">В корзину</a>
```

Comment: Поставил, но код не работает

Comment: @steep я в `html` добавил `id` для `select` и `label`, добавил их у себя?

Comment: Да. А сама кнопка `<a` такая же должна быть?

Comment: @steep исправил код, попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Тоже не работает

Comment: @steep тебе же нужно `data-size`  в ссылке менять при изменении выбранного размера?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79327/discussion-between-nikita-smith-and-steep).

Comment: Да! Но он так и остаётся пустой

Comment: @steep перейди в чат

Comment: Нужно чтобы было примерно так `data-size="38-XXS"`

Comment: @steep в пример это работает, ты просто что-то пропустил, скопируй код заново

Comment: Ничего я не пропустил. И в примере Error

Comment: @steep [изображение](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/06/25/0027/0942/1774510/10/f920fc6cf6.jpg)

Comment: На codepen проверил, работает только при повторном нажатии на select. А при нажатии на option не работает. А на сайте вообще не работает. Может есть какой другой способ? И ссылок у меня на странице несколько, не будут же у них одинаковые `id`